# Creating a c-array of CGPoints

Tags: ios, c, arrays, struct

I'd like to create a constant array of CGPoints in a c style array.

I started with this but got the error `Initializer element is not a compile time constant`

```
static CGPoint locations[5] = 
{
    CGPointMake(180, 180),
    CGPointMake(300, 130),
    CGPointMake(435, 120),
    CGPointMake(470, 230),
    CGPointMake(565, 200),
};
```

I removed the `static` thinking it might be something to do with that, but the error remained.

How can you create an array of CGPoints (and more widely, any similarly defined struct).

---

<sub>NB: I've posted this question and answer partially for my own reference as I can never remember this off the top of my head and waste too much time researching the answer from other sources. Here's hoping it helps others!</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the `CGPointMake` function call is the thing that "isn't a compile time constant" and so the CGPoints need to be treated like raw structs:

```
static CGPoint locations[5] = 
{
    (CGPoint){180, 180},
    (CGPoint){300, 130},
    (CGPoint){435, 120},
    (CGPoint){470, 230},
    (CGPoint){565, 200},
};
```

The cast isn't strictly required, but for my own sanity, I'd keep it to show each of those numbers is actually part of a CGPoint. This is also valid:

```
static CGPoint locations[5] = {
    {180, 180},
    {300, 130},
    {435, 120},
    {470, 230},
    {565, 200},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function is always a runtime activity. The contents of an array initializer list needs to be computed at compilation time.

Comment: Calling a non-`constexpr` function is always a runtime activity. Calling a `constexpr` function can be a compile-time thing depending on context and/or optimization settings.

Comment: @rubenvb `constexpr` doesn't exist in C, which the question is tagged as.